# Can I sort my SQLAlchemyAutoSchema manually?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I've just started working with the `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` package in python for my flask application. All works fine and the api spits out the content of my database, but seems to sort the fields alphabetically as opposed to the order I have created them using the SQLAlchemy.Model class. Now I was wondering if there is a way to prohibit that or at least sort the fields somehow manually?

This is how I create my database table:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    p_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    p_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    p_type = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    p_size = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    p_color = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Product(name={self.p_name}, type={self.p_type}, size={self.p_size}, color={self.p_color})"
```

And this is my schema:

```
class ProductSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        ordered = True     #I have read about this property on another post, but doesn't do anything here
        model = Product
```

My function returning the content in json format:

```
    def get(self, id):
        if id:
            product = Product.query.filter_by(p_id=id).first()
            if product:
                product_schema = ProductSchema()
                output = product_schema.dump(product)
            else:
                abort(Response('product not found', 400))
        else:
            products = Product.query.all()
            products_schema = ProductSchema(many=True)
            output = products_schema.dump(products)
        return jsonify(output), 200
```

Aaand the output I get (alphabetically sorted):

```
[
  {
    "p_color": "test color1", 
    "p_id": 1, 
    "p_name": "test name1", 
    "p_size": 8, 
    "p_type": "test type1"
  }, 
  {
    "p_color": "test color2", 
    "p_id": 2, 
    "p_name": "test name2", 
    "p_size": 8, 
    "p_type": "test type2"
  }, 
  {
    "p_color": "test color3", 
    "p_id": 3, 
    "p_name": "test name3", 
    "p_size": 8, 
    "p_type": "test type3"
  }, 
  {
    "p_color": "test color4", 
    "p_id": 4, 
    "p_name": "test name4", 
    "p_size": 8, 
    "p_type": "test type4"
  }
]
```

As described above, my application is fully functional. But I'd at least like to know what's going on. So any help is apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Flask sorts the keys when dumping json output. This is done so that the order is deterministic, which allows to compute hashes and such.

See [the docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#module-flask.json).

You may disable this with the [`JSON_SORT_KEYS`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#JSON_SORT_KEYS) parameter.

If you want to debug the marshallow part, just print the dump (`output`) in your view function.

Unless you have a good reason to force the output order, you're probably better-off just letting it go.

Note: In flask-smorest, I don't mind the payload being alphabetically ordered in the responses but I like it ordered when publishing the OpenAPI spec file, so I don't modify `JSON_SORT_KEYS` and in the resource serving the spec file, [I don't use `jsonify` but raw json.dumps](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-smorest/blob/c78a06dc83955080a3eb456717056e92e0649fa5/flask_smorest/spec/__init__.py#L83-L89).

Comment: Thanks! I was focusing on the wrong package looking for an answer... This helped!